# Execute Package using SQL

Tags: ssis

How is it possible to execute a SSIS 2008 Package by using SQL in SQL Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly from TSQL (you would have to use [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) to run DTEXEC, but that's not recommended)

You can execute a SSIS Package:

1. Using SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)
2. Using the DTEXEC.EXE Command Line Utility
3. Using a SQL Server Agent Job
4. Using the DTEXECUI.EXE Utility

[How to: Run a Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138023.aspx)

Can you explain why you need to run from TSQL?

Comment: In  our application we have a command button to call a Stored Procedure which will execute the package. And its a requirement too. Thats why I asked about executing package using TSQL.

Comment: command used in TSQL for executing ssis package. I found in one of our projects. the syntax is xp_cmdshell '<<DTEXEC SSIS_PATH>>'

Comment: that's what I said in the first line of my answer!

Comment: @Sreejesh Kumar: if this answer helped you please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Comment: Its not working. I am executing a file system path. the error shown after executing in TSQL, is " Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML format. A specific XML parser error will be posted."

Comment: but when i executed without xp_cmdshell ie in Command Prompt window, its working.

Comment: Please amend your question. Provide the stored procedure and sample parameters so that we can help you.

Comment: @Sreejesh Kumar: Please post the additional information that's been asked for. Our product uses on-demand execution of SSIS packages using SQL Agent jobs & it works fine, but we don't have enough to go on to help here.